# How to preview Android ListView with custom row and header layout

Tags: android, layout, android-studio

I have created a list view with a custom layout for the header and rows items many times but what always annoys me is the UI preview in Android Studio does not show a preview. Obviously because the custom layouts are loaded programmatically by the ListView or CursorAdapter but what if I wanted to some how specify a header and footer layout in xml so that I could see a preview. Any one know how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [tools:listitem](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)?

Comment: @Salem Interesting. That does not show up in auto complete for me but it works. Thanks. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use [`tools:listitem`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes). Just add the tools namespace in the root of the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    (...)
```

and then in your ListView set your list item layout

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylistView"
    tools:listitem="@layout/my_list_item"
    (...)
```

[image]

Is also possible to set header/footer with `listheader`/`listfooter`.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the Item 1, Item 2 from the view on the right?

Comment: turns out in Android Studio, the listview needs to have an id attribute set before the listitem preview will show up.

Comment: Thanks @Maks you have saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace are using for development purposes(preview) and are not compiled in the application.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listfooter="@layout/item_footer"
    tools:listheader="@layout/item_header"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item" />
```