# The listView is not displaying items in the Design tab, but is displaying in the emulator

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

The problem is that, the listView is not displaying correctly in the design tab of my activity_main xml, but is displaying correctly in the emulator that is running. This is inconvenient since,  its pretty convenient to see the design in the Design tab.

**Please tell me how to solve this.**

[emulator with design tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrqCx.png)

My code is as follows:`

1.Main_activity.java:

```
package com.example.lemonade.app1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.lemonade.app1.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Array of strings...
    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Strings.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
        <string name="app_name">ListDisplay</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
 </resources>
```

activity_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/label"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="10dip"
     android:textSize="16dip"
     android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: See answer to this question, if I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193983/how-to-preview-android-listview-with-custom-row-and-header-layout

Answer (score 0):

I can think on 2 problems that you may have:

1)Please check the min SDK in you'r app module and the phone you are trying to run the app on maybe the min SDK is higher then you'r phone.

2)You trying to show image View on you'r list View and they coped as "V21",When you trying to copy image into your drawable library it give you 2 option regular image or V21 for some reason the v21 don't show on phones and on emulators they do,well for me at least because i had the same problem and it solve it to me.

If one of these didnt helped try to debug it and tell me what results you got.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the action bar showing in your design but not the emulator? It sounds like you have your app theme set to include an action bar and your design preview is showing it assuming you are using it.

I can't test it right now but I believe if you don't explicitly set up your options in your activity by overriding onCreateOptionsMenu(), which you aren't, it will not show the action bar when you run your app.

You can check your app theme in your manifest and/or styles.xml, look for

```
"android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Which points to styles.xml in my case.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

If you change the parent to something without the action bar, Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar for example, it will not show in your design window.